# It's possible to put a div below other if the parent div is flex and its width is below 300px, without using grid?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need a responsive behavior on this. Should work as follows.

I have two block divs inside a flex div, like this:

**CSS**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="image.jpg" class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="column2">
    <p>This is an image description on the right side. This text should be under the image if div.container width is below 300px.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Current result based on the previous code (width: ~520px):**

[image: Duck on the left, text on the right]

**But if the container width is below 300px (~260px in this example), I need this result (without using grid):**

[image: Duck on top, text below.]

Answer (score 1):

The flex-wrap CSS property sets whether flex items are forced onto one line or can wrap onto multiple lines so you Just add `flex-wrap: wrap` to your container class

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class which has the `flex-direction` set as `column`. This will make the blocks appear one below the other (within the flex). Below are some code snippets taken from a working code.

```
.container2 {
    display: flex;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Modify the container div's class based on a condition like below.

For Eg.: If the container width is greater than 300, use the existing class `container`, or else use the newly created class `container2`.

```
<div #dynamiccontainer [ngClass]=" contentWidth >= 300 ? 'container' : 'container2'">
    .....
</div>
```

Get the element reference of the container using `@ViewChild`.

```
@ViewChild('dynamiccontainer') elementView: ElementRef;
```

Define a variable to store the container width.

```
contentWidth: number;
```

Get the container width using the element reference created.

```
getContainerWidthUsingElementView() {
    this.contentWidth = this.elementView.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
}
```

Call this above method to update the container width whenever required.

For Eg.: After View Initialisation, and whenever there is a change in the window size.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.getContainerWidthUsingElementView();
}

@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
    this.getContainerWidthUsingElementView();
}
```